# Dynamic check checkbox Kendo UI web ListView

Tags: checkbox, kendo-ui, kendo-datasource, kendo-listview

I have a Kendo UI Web ListView control with a check box template :

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="tplListeGroupe">

<div class="item click" data="${Id}">
    <input type="checkbox" class="click" />
    <span class="idPermission" name="idPermission">#:Id#</span>
    <span class="checkbox" name="nomPermission">#:Nom#</span>
</div>
```

I fill the content from a datasource bound to a remote service

```
$("#gridListePermissions").kendoListView({
        dataSource: dataSourcePermissions,
        template: kendo.template($("#tplListeGroupe").html()),
        headertemplate: "<div class='item click' id='headerTemp' data='*'><input type='checkbox' class='click' /></div>",
        dataBound: function (e) {
            checkboxEventBinding();
        }
    });

$.each(dataSourcePermissions._data, function (j) {
        alert(dataSourcePermissions._data[j].Id + " " + dataSourcePermissions._data[j].Nom);
        //For example. Here's where I want to compare and check

    });
```

The problem is that I want to check some values based on data that I get from another service (in the changed event of a dropdownlist control). But I cannot see how can I do this ? Should I iterate through the ListView instead of the datasource ?